# Find the probability density function for the function $E = d^2$

Tags: statistics

I'm struggling with this text book question

"Suppose $d$ is a Gaussian random variable with zero mean and unit variance. What is the probability density function of: $E$ = $d^2$?

Hint: Since the sign of d gets lost when it is squared, you can assume that p(d) is one-sided, that is, defined for only $d \geq 0$ and with twice the amplitude of the usual Gaussian."

Intuitively this is the way I would attempt it:

if $E=d^2$ then $d=\sqrt{E}$ (considering only when d is positive),

then substituting this into the equation for the normal distribution $2*N(1,0)$ returns:
$\large{ \frac{2}{(\sqrt(2*\pi))}\exp{(-x/2)}}$

Taking the derivative of this would give me p(d). This sort of feels right since the derivative will be negative everywhere and tends to zero.

If some one could shed some light on the concepts here it would be greatly appreciated I don't have much if any experience with probability (or latex for that matter). 
Thanks if advance!

Answer (score 0):

**Comments:** (a) You should look at @angryavian's suggested link, and at the
Wikipedia link there.

(b) There is a standard formula for the density function of a on-to-one transformation
of a random variable with a given density function. You can use it for this
problem by first finding the distribution of the absolute normal $Y=|Z|,$ where
$Z \sim \mathsf{Norm}(0.1).$ As usual, denote the density of $Z$ as $\varphi(z),$
then the  density of $Y$ is $2\varphi(y),$ for $y > 0.$ Finally, the
transformation from $Y$ to $X =  Z^2$ is 1-to-1 and you can use the standard formula. To compare your result with Wikipedia $(k=1),$ recall that $\Gamma(1/2) = \sqrt{\pi}.$

(c) The distribution of $Z^2$ is called the chi-squared distribution with
one degree of freedom. It's pdf is $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1\pi}}x^{-.5}e^{-x/2},$ for $x > 0.$ It has $E(X) = 1$ and $V(X) = 2.$
In R statistical software `dchisq` with
second parameter $1$ is the PDF of $X.$ The trivial simulation (in R) below with
a histogram of simulated values of $X$ illustrates this result.

```
m = 10^6;  z = rnorm(m);  x = z^2  # a million realizations of Z, then square
mean(x);  sd(x)
## 1.001816        # aprx E(X) = 1
## 1.414747        # aprx SD(X) = sqrt(2)
hist(x, prob=T, br=20, col="skyblue2", main="Simulation and PDF of CHISQ(1)")
curve(dchisq(x, 1), col="red", lwd=2, n=1001, add=T)
```

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks so much! This has been great, i've answered the question and gone through the material you suggested. Thank you